# Geo-spatial MongoDB Pizza Restaurant Query. Is the 2dSphere index correct?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial, mongo-shell, spatial-query

I'm stuck on a homework question regarding using the Mongodb shell to query two geo-spatial data collections. Which are as follows:

An example record from the restaurants dataset is:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55cba2476c522cafdb053ae8"),
"location" : {
"coordinates" : [
-73.9973325,
40.61174889999999
],
"type" : "Point"
},
"name" : "C & C Catering Service"
}
```

An example record from the zipcodes dataset is:

```
{
"_id" : "01002",
"city" : "CUSHMAN",
"loc" : [
-72.51565,
42.377017
],
"pop" : 36963,
"state" : "MA"
}
```

The question is :
For each Pizza restaurant from the above set, find the city that it is located in. You can assume that a restaurant is located in the nearest city to its location.

I have created the variable for finding the pizza restaurants:

```
var pizza = db.restaurants.find({"name" : /pizza/i});
```

I created these indexes but not sure weather I need a compound index.

```
db.zipcodes.createIndex({"loc" : "2dsphere"});
db.restaurants.createIndex({"location" : "2dsphere"});
```

Are these indexes correct? and if so what should I use for creating the query? Aggregate as well as $nearSphere?